# Lambda function triggered when adding files to a S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am having a problem with the behavior of a Lambda function. Ultimately, I want my lambda function to read some information about json files that I upload to my S3 bucket. Here is a test function:

```
import boto3
import json

s3=boto3.client('s3')

def LambdaHandler(event,context):
#    bucket=event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
#    key=event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    try:
        print('I was triggered')

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise e
```

Note the two lines that are commented. I believe that I used the correct role and permissions, since the logs on AWS show that the function is triggered each time I upload a file to my S3 bucket (the log shows "I was triggered").

The problem is that, when I uncomment the two lines, the log no longer show anything. It is like the function is no longer triggered. Am I missing something?

I am expecting at this point the log to still show that the function is triggered (and display the message "I was triggered"). Ultimately I want the function to read the json files that I'm uploading, so that I can make it take some further action.

Comment: Can you share the Event you are testing this lambda with?

Comment: Try starting simple. Add this line to the start of the Lambda function: `print(event)`. That should show the contents of the `event` parameter in the logs. When viewing the logs in CloudWatch Logs, make sure you go back one level to view a fresh link, because publishing a new version of the function generates a new log file.

Comment: Alright, I don't know what happened, but I deleted everything from AWS and created the whole thing again, and now it works. My Lambda function can read the files that are uploaded to the S3 bucket.

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: I edited your question title to remove the "Solved". Please mark the answer that has solved your question! This gives reputation to answerer and is the essence of how Stack Overflow works. It also will indicate it next to the question anyway. (and you receive some reputation as well). Note that if you can also write a "real" answer yourself and mark this one as accepted. It's better for future readers, as comments are meant to be temporary and can be cleaned up at any times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that there is an error reading the `event` dictionary. [Lambda should be publishing logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-logging.html) regardless of the print statement runs or not. You will see in those logs if one of the commented lines fails.

As a general Python thing, your try/except statement doesn't really add much value. The statement you are trying will always succeed, so I'm not really sure what exception you are attempting to catch there.

My suggestion is to remove the try/except block entirely and place the print statement above your two statements which read from the `event` object. That way you know the lambda function will print logs regardless and you can further debug your issue.

Comment: So, I tried with this Lambda:
____________
import boto3
import json

s3=boto3.client('s3')

def LambdaHandler(event,context):
    print('I was triggered!')
    print('I'm also printing this.)
___________

I used a role with the following permissions:
    'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess',
    'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaExecute',
    'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole'

So, there is only the print statements, but now the function is no longer triggered!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I don't know what happened, but I deleted everything from AWS and created the whole thing again, and now it works. My Lambda function can read the files that are uploaded to the S3 bucket. Problem fully solve.